# Where can I find 'public function getIncludes()' or $this->getIncludes()?

Tags: magento

I am trying to edit some CSS that is getting loaded in a custom CMS page via `echo $this->getIncludes()`

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<?php echo $this->getIncludes(); ?>` Gets the string as you entered from the Magento admin panel.

You can edit it in `System > Configuration > Design > HTML Head > Miscellaneous Scripts`. Your CSS should be there to edit, if that call is what is adding the styles. If it is an external sheet that is referenced then you will need to find it in your directory and edit it there, but you probably knew that.

Comment: Thank you so much on explaining where `$this->getIncludes()` comes from! I still can't find it in the `HTML Head > Miscellaneous Scripts`. When I remove `$this->getIncludes()` it is gone though; am I going crazy?

Comment: What version are you using? It's under system configuration, under the "general" left navigation column and "design". Expand "HTML Head" in the content area (after "Packages" and "Themes"), you should see it after "Default Keywords" and "Default Robots".